# $ref in Json Schema with specified values

Tags: javascript, json, schema

I'm trying to build a schema that references another schema. However in my schema I would like to specify that certain properties specified by the referenced schema have particular values without modifying that referenced schema.

For example with a schema like this:

```
{
  "definitions" : {
    "name" : {
      "properties" : {
        "firstName" : { "type" : "string" },
        "lastName"  : { "type" : "string" }
      },
      "required" : ["firstName", "lastName"]
    }
  },
  "properties" : {
    "clientName"    : { "$ref" : "#/definitions/name" }
  },
  "required" : [ "clientName" ]
}
```

I would somehow like to validate objects that have firstName equal to "Bob".

So this should validate:

```
{ 
  "clientName" : {
    "firstName" : "Bob",
    "lastName"  : "Doe"
  }
}
```

But this should not:

```
{ 
  "clientName" : {
    "firstName" : "Fred",
    "lastName"  : "Doe"
  }
}
```

Without modifying the "definitions" block in my schema, how can I express this restriction?